# Javascript loader issue

Tags: javascript

Im currently developing a website and i have the most basic code on it at the moment and i went to add a "loader" however it says one of my lines of code in my javascript file is broken and cant figure out why. i am a beginner so that might be why. however when i load the website in a browser the loader works but it doesnt fade and show the website it just keeps spinning.

Below is my java code :

```
<script>
var myVar;

function myFunction() {
myVar = setTimeout(showPage, 3000);
}

function showPage() {
document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

And here is my HTML code for the loader :

```
<body onload="myFunction()" style="margin:0;">

<div id="loader"></div>

<div style="display:none;" id="myDiv" class="animate-bottom">
<h2>Tada!</h2>
<p>Some text in my newly loaded page..</p>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: You need to call `myFunction()` in some part to make it work

Comment: @Igor `myFunction()` is being called in the `<body onload=`

Comment: `however it says one of my lines of code in my javascript file is broken` -- what says? which line? where do you see this?

Comment: `Below is my java code :` -- where is your java code?  Do you mean JavaScript?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/ec292f35cafbe7d895ad694b0ef08171 this is the error im getting in dreamweaver @vol7ron

Comment: Make sure the script is loaded into the page that calls myFunction() in onload event. You can check if myFunction is called adding an alert() inside the function code.

Comment: @igor the script should be loaded as ive used this code in the head of my html document <script src="myjavascript.js"></script>

Comment: Why is getting an error? Your javascript code is in a .js file? So, you dont need to add <script> tags to that file?

Comment: I removed the <script> tags and it now works, thank you @igor

Answer (score 0):

Works for me.  It's not an issue with your browser or code:

```js
var myVar;

function myFunction() {
  myVar = setTimeout(showPage, 3000);
}

function showPage() {
  document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<body onload="myFunction()" style="margin:0;">

  <div id="loader"></div>

  <div style="display:none;" id="myDiv" class="animate-bottom">
    <h2>Tada!</h2>
    <p>Some text in my newly loaded page..</p>
  </div>

</body>
```

Given the [screenshot of your error](https://gyazo.com/ec292f35cafbe7d895ad694b0ef08171), this may be a Dreamweaver issue.  Perhaps `setTimeout` doesn't exist, or the application isn't properly hoisting your function.

You can try:

- moving `showPage` function above your `myFunction` in the code
- qualifying your `setTimeout` with `window.setTimeout`
- removing the `<script>` elements from your JavaScript

Sidenote:

- add `"use strict";` to the top of your JavaScript files to detect and prevent future errors sooner.

Comment: If there is no issue then i dont understand why dreamweaver is saying there is one